# Generating Dynamic value for class in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

In my app i want to add dynamic number to each class of div for creating a dynamic twitter bootstrap grid class.for example col-md-2 or col-md-3. and then repeat from these div :

```
 <div class="row" ng-repeat="row in placeholders">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div ng-repeat="column in row.columns" class="col-md-{{12 / row.columns.length}} biki"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and this is the model :

```
  $scope.placeholders = [{
            name: "Row 1",
            showName: true,
            columns: [{
                name: "Col1 in Row 1",
            }, {
                name: "Col2 in Row 1"
            }]

    }, {
            name: "Row 2",
            showName: true,
            columns: [{
                name: "Col 1 in Row 2",
            }, {
                name: "Col 2 in Row 2"
            },
             {
                name: "Col 3 in Row 2"
            }]

    }]
```

So if the length of columns array in object is 6 it divided by 12 and create 6 div with `col-md-2` class. The problem happen when length of array is 5 or 8. If 5 the number is divided by 12 is 2.4 and twitter bootstrap have not any value for 2.4 so I want to `parseInt` or solve the problem with other way but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: use `Math.ceil()` to round up. [See MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil)

Comment: I can not use Math.ceil() or ParseInt() in angular expression it dose'nt work

Comment: can simply use a scope function in expression `class="{{getClass(row)}}"`

Comment: This can be fixed using a filter. Demo : http://jsbin.com/bahoze/4/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/bahoze/4/edit)**

Create this filter:

```
myApp.filter('parseInt', function () {
    return function(a,b){
        return(parseInt(a))
    }
});
```

Now in your view:

```
class="col-md-{{12 / row.columns.length | parseInt}} biki"
```

This will do the trick :)